# Digital temperature detector

Tags: sensor, temperature, detector

I am using LM95071 temp detector IC for temp sensing.

Link for datasheet:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snis137d/snis137d.pdf

Its a digital temp detector, it will show equivalent ADC count.

But where we assign BUF register in ADC to read count, I mean in which register, the temp equivalent digital count will be store? Where we do this assignment?

[image: LM 95071 configuration with controller]

Answer (score 1):

There is no register assignment necessary except in your MCU since, in concert with 3 MCU I/Os, the LM95071 merely accepts serial commands from the MCU and spits out serial data which the MCU will read and assemble to an area, external to the LM95071, which your program will specify.

Read the **SERIAL BUS INTERFACE** section of the data sheet for greater insight into the process.